# Search by ID in the CP

Tags: search

Unless I'm missing something, it seems like it is impossible to search by ID in the CP (and therefore via ElementCriteriaModel's search).

I know you can make it sortable using `modifyEntrySortableAttributes`, but it still doesn't make it searchable.

I've also tried id::"123", which doesn't work.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you analyze POST request you will see this:

[image]

To get items by id you need to create custom request and add criteria[id]=(int id here) e.x. use [this](https://coderwall.com/p/-fdgoq/chrome-developer-tools-adds-copy-as-curl)

It is most likely related to the way how `ElementCriteriaModel` works (99% sure) :

```
craft.entries({
    id: 123, // search by ID*
    search: 'search query'
})
```

[search by ID*](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#id)

`craft.entries` returns `ElementCriteriaModel` - [Source](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries)

You won't be able to use default CP search form to get entries by ID